# Binding a const l-value reference to r-value is fine but not vice versa

Tags: c++

So, I've been studying about `std::move()` and I came across l-value and r-value reference and a question popped in my mind -

Consider a code here :

```
#include <iostream>
int fun(int arg){
    return arg;
}
int main() {
    // Write C++ code here
    int a=10;
    std::cout<<fun(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Now if I want l-value arg to accept r-value I have to declare it `const`, like in this case -:

```
#include <iostream>
int fun(const int& arg){
    return arg;
}
int main() {
    // Write C++ code here
    int a=10;
    std::cout<<fun(a);
    std::cout<<fun(10); //both will work fine
    return 0;
}
```

But if I do vice-versa i.e. using r-value const

```
#include <iostream>
int fun(const int&& arg){
    return arg;
}
int main() {
    // Write C++ code here
    int a=10;
    std::cout<<fun(a);  // error
    std::cout<<fun(10); 
    return 0;
}
```

Its showing error like -:

```
> cpp:9:20: error: cannot bind rvalue reference of type 'const int&&' to lvalue of type 'int'
> 9 |     std::cout<<fun(a);
>       |                    ^
> /tmp/ufgkAH4KAC.cpp:3:21: note:   initializing argument 1 of 'int fun(const int&&)'
> 3 | int fun(const int&& arg){
>       |         ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
>
```

Can anyone explain me why?

Comment: tl; dr: Why is `int n{}; const int&& ref = n;` rejected?

Comment: @Kroky_Glauttas For information, both `fun(a);` and `fun(10);` works for the first example. Other thing, the error for the last example is not for `fun(10);` but for `fun(a);` !

Comment: @Fareanor Yes, thank you, corrected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the error comes from

```
std::cout<<fun(a)
```

As seen from the error:

```
 error: cannot bind rvalue reference of type 'const int&&' to lvalue of type 'int' 9 | std::cout<<fun(a);
```

Because as it mentions, `a` here is an a l-value and you are using a function which takes an r-value, so you can cast it to an r-value with a std::move e.g.:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
int fun(const int&& arg){
    return arg;
}
int main() {
    int a = 10;
    std::cout << fun(std::move(a)) << std::endl;
    std::cout << fun(10) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

See https://godbolt.org/z/59TfdPrsa

Stroustrup has a good paper on the differences between l-values and r-values here: https://www.stroustrup.com/terminology.pdf

With r-values you can make use of things such as move constructors, as you can essentially take a value and take ownership of that. So when you `std::move(a)` you have to be careful as any access to `a` after `fun(std::move(a))` may be undefined

Comment: Yes, I got it, but my question was, the const & arg  can take both l-value and r-value, why const && arg cannot take both value

Comment: @Kroky_Glauttas "C++ deliberately specifies that binding a temporary object to a reference to const on the stack lengthens the lifetime of the temporary to the lifetime of the reference itself" and then const &&arg is just taking an r-value, and there's nothing similar to have an l-value passed to it. Have a look [here](https://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/)

Answer (score 2):

When we see `&&` in function argument mean that function is going to take ownership from that one (by `std::move` or `std::forward`).

So you will see nobody use `const type&& param` but only `type&& param` in use.